# Determining at run-time which styles an element has implemented via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to use JavaScript to get the computed style of an element whose style has been changed by a stylesheet. The element's style is not changed via inline CSS, meaning that the [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style) property doesn't help at all. The only function I found in HTML that might help is getComputedStyle.

The problem with using [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle) is that it returns all the properties of an element even if the stylesheet hasn't redefined it for that element.

For example, say I have the following stylesheet:

```
body {
  font-size: 13px;
}
div {
  color: blue;
}
.example {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

... and the following HTML:

```
<body>
  <div>
    This is a <span class="example">test</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

When I run the following JavaScript on the span element:

```
window.getComputedStyle(spanElement)
```

... I get all the CSS attributes for that element:

```
background-attachment: scroll; background-clip: border-box; background-color: 
rgb(255, 255, 255); background-image: none; background-origin: padding-box; 
[...] 
text-anchor: start; writing-mode: lr-tb; glyph-orientation-horizontal: 0deg; 
glyph-orientation-vertical: auto; -webkit-svg-shadow: none; vector-effect: none;
```

What I want is only the styles that the element has redefined (i.e. those which aren't inherited), in this example, it would be:

```
font-weight: bold;
```

Is there any easy way to get this information? If not, what would be the best way to get these results? Ideally I want a solution/algorithm which would be fast to run on hundreds of these elements.

Originally I thought I could loop over the node's parent elements and compare all the values to determine which ones aren't inherited, but it seems very inefficient to compare a hundred or so attributes for every single node. There are only a dozen or so different classes, but each one can occur hundreds of times, therefore, some sort of caching mechanism could improve performance dramatically.

My first idea of how to cache the values was to store the class name and its value (e.g. `cachedValues['.example'] := 'font-weight: bold;'`). The problem with this method is that CSS selectors can be very complicated. For example, some properties are inherited from their parents, meaning that a span not inside a div will be rendered differently in my original CSS example. So I thought I could include the parent in the cached values as well (e.g. `cachedValues['div span.example'] := 'font-weight: bold;'`). The problem here is that CSS selectors can get much more complicated with pseudo classes such as [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3afirst-child).

Example CSS:

```
div:first-child {
  color: red;
}
div {
  color: blue;
}
```

Example HTML:

```
<body>
  <div>Red line</div>
  <div>Blue line</div>
</body>
```

In this example, if I stored `cachedValues['div'] := 'font-color: red;'`, it would be incorrect for the second line.

Do you have any suggestions as to how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Maybe you can get the external css file by examining link elements in the head and parse that.

Comment: How is this meant to be used? If not directly on the web page, can it be made as a browser extension? Firebug is already able to do this for individual elements. You can write a firebug extension that simply outputs this information for each element.

Comment: Any browser restrictions? If you are using getComputedStyle you are leaving out IE

Comment: @Box9: I'm looking for a solution that works directly on the page.

Comment: @Hemlock: I'm mainly interested in getting it to work on Chrome, but compatibility with FF and Safari doesn't hurt. It seems like IE would require too much custom logic, so it's not important to support it.

Comment: I think my answer to this question will do it for you in chrome. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471663/window-getcomputedstyle-how-to-discard-properties-with-default-values/4481016#4481016

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna have to implement a CSS engine, which is not an easy task.

The guys from [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.3/firebug-lite.js) have done it. You may want to have a look at their `getElementRules` and `getInheritedRules` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [these tests from Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/stylesheets.html).  You should be able to access the stylesheets with `document.styleSheets` and parse that.

Of particular note are the `cssText` tests.  They seem to grab all the rules of a particular selector.

Comment: This could work as a one-time cached thing. You iterate over all selectors from `document.styleSheets`, then use jQuery to select the objects matching those selectors, and cache the results per element. Although, I'm not sure how you'd handle conflicting selectors, with one overriding another.

Answer (score 0):

Probably wat you can do is that , keep a separate  javascript file (anyname.js) or may be inline script would also do and declare somthing lik this

$(document).ready(function () {

$('# ').each(function () {

```
 $('# <div name>').css({ 'font-weight': 'bold' });

}
```

}