# Computed style of background-position returns 0% 0% in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have an `element`, and I want to see its `background-position`:

I do this:

```
window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('background-position')
```

If the attribute background-position is not defined for that `element`, I get:

```
0% 0%
```

However, if I decide to set the `background-position` to `0% 0%`, I would get the same value.

How can I differentiate between those two cases? How can I know that the attribute is actually defined?

EDIT:

Others have suggested to just use `style.getPropertyValue('background-position')`, but that would just take into account INLINE values. I want to take into account also if the value has been set in an external CSS file. http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#elementcssinlinestyle

Comment: Look for `background-position` or `background` in `element.style`?

Comment: You get `0% 0%` because it's the dafault value... maybe if you set another value at the begin of css then you can difference this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but what if I want to use the computedStyle?

Comment: Danko, this is not my own CSS. I am parsing sites.

Comment: Why do you need to differentiate between the initial value and a set value?

Comment: You want to computedStyle for what? Your Q was how to find out if it is defined or just taking default value. The answer to this was in my comment.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp If it's an answer, it should be an answer. Not a comment with a question mark.

Comment: My question was how to differentiate between the computedValue of a defined 0% 0% background-position, and with one that is not defined, which right now seems to be both 0% 0%.

Comment: @MrLister because I want to make sure that the value is not just one that might be inline. What if it has been set by an external CSS file?

Comment: Again, why does it matter? So what if the style was set by an inline attribute or a `<style>` element in the head or an external CSS file? So what if it's the default, set by the normal CSS cascade or with an `!important` modifier? All that doesn't matter for the end result.

Comment: Mr Lister. It matters, because ```element.style``` will just look for styles that are INLINE. If the attribute has been set by an external file, I won't be able to get it if I use ```element.style```

Answer (score 2):

The computed value is correct since [`0% 0%` is the initial value for `background-position`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds/#the-background-position). (CSS properties always have a value – even if only an initial one – so are never really "undefined".)

`getComputedStyle` can't tell you the difference, but might choose to assume, e.g., that background-position `0% 0%` with background-image `none` might represent the initial value.

To trace where styles come from, try the nonstandard `getMatchedCSSRules()` (cf. [window.getComputedStyle(): How to Discard properties with default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4471663/822138)).

Answer (score 0):

Imho, the only difference between these 2 cases is before any browser-side css parsing. this means you have to investigate css string-wise to determine if it has been set or not. searching for 'background' and 'background-position' as a substring, then finding out if you have 0 or 0% or not