# Find list of all CSS class rules (from multiple stylesheets) and their active properties for the selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to get all the matched CSS Selectors for a selected element as well as get the properties of each class that are active for that element.

So far I have looked into `getMatchedCSSRules` and http://www.brothercake.com/site/resources/scripts/cssutilities/

I don't want to use the cssutilities library because it doesn't get updated if anything changes on the page inside the stylesheets through Javascript (it creates its own rules array which needs to be updated again and again after every change that occurs using Javascript in any of the style tags)

Basically, what I need is what `getMatchedCSSRules` returns in chrome but for each property in each rule, I need an extra property like "active" which tell whether the current property is active or is overridden by some other class.

It needs to work in Webkit and Firefox (I am using a polyfill for Gecko for `getMatchedCSSRules`)

Return should be like - 
CSSRulesAffectingElement = {

```
     rule : {
           text:"<css rule's text>,
           properties : {
              property1:{value:<value>,status:<active,cancelled>}
           }
        }
     }
```

Example - //when active fontsize is coming from some other rule

```
colorclass:
{
    csstext:'background-color:red;font-size:12px',
    properties: 
    {
        Background-color:
        {
            value:'red',
            status:'active'
        },
        Font-size:
        {
            value:'12px',
            status:'cancelled'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471663/window-getcomputedstyle-how-to-discard-properties-with-default-values

Comment: @SHAYAN I need to get the class where each rule is coming from as well... and not just check for whether or not it is a "default" value..

Comment: You might use the debug inspector of chrome or firefox?
It's a big work so do not code it yourself.

Comment: Seconding what the person above me said - is there are reason you're not using the developer tools in your browser?

Comment: I am creating a inspector tool inside the browser.. so needed it for that..

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible unless parsing actual CSS files. I was into that and found out that it was what less.js is doing.

You can check their code on git hub, maybe it helps:

https://github.com/less/less.js

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and looking into LESS source as well as firebug, I realized that the quickest method was to use the library http://www.brothercake.com/site/resources/scripts/cssutilities/ and tweak its working to suit my needs..

The `getCSSRules()` method provides with all the css classes (including the inherited ones)  and their properties that are affecting the element. It is an expensive method for sure but I was able to place it selectively in my application to fit the bill..

Comment: Maybe you should read the source code of chrome's and firefox's dev tool.

Comment: @cuixiping Yeah, ended up doing that. I used the Firebug's method of maintaining the CSS Styles in memory and sorting them to find an elements applied classes etc.